# CSS file in asp.net website

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, visual-studio

I have css file reference in my website which is shown as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://go/css/filename.css">
```

I need to alter the CSS file and upload it in the new location.

Is it possible to put it in my local system or can I upload it in same website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file and put it next to your .html file. Change the link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename.css">
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i expected!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSS file from an external site, you won't be able to modify it in place unless you also have access to the source for that site.  Your best bet is to use something like Firefox/Firebug to get access to the CSS source, copy and modify the CSS to do what you need it to do, then put it in your local site and maintain it there from then on.

Comment: i could download the file and edit it ... how i can put in local site?

or is it possible to put in my c drive ?